# If it exists, estimate the limit of the sequence x, where $x_n$ = $(1$ if $n=1$, and $2\sqrt{ x_{n-1}}$ if $n \geq 2$)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

My attempt:
$x_1 = 1,  x_2 = 2\sqrt1 = 2, x_3 = 2 \sqrt2, x_4 = 2\sqrt{2\sqrt2}, x_5 = 2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt2}}$

After trying to figure out these numbers in the sequence I have no clue where this is converging, if it is even converging. I can't think of any other technique to use. For the problem before I did this technique and it told me the sequence diverged.

Comment: Hint: $$
\begin{array}{rll}
x_1 &= 2^0 &= 2^{2-2^{1}}\\
x_2 &= 2^{2^{-0}} &= 2^{2-2^{-0}}\\
x_3 &= 2^{2^{-0} + 2^{-1}} &= 2^{2-2^{-1}}\\
x_4 &= 2^{2^{-0} + 2^{-1} + 2^{-2}} &= 2^{2-2^{-2}}
\end{array}
$$
Can you see the pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = 2 \sqrt{x}$, then the iteration is of the form
$x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$.

Since $f$ is continuous, if $x_n \to x$ we must have $f(x) = x$.

It is generally a good idea to plot $x \mapsto f(x)$ and $x \mapsto x$ to
look for obvious fixed points.

[image]

Note that for $x \in [0,4]$, $x \le f(x) \le 4$.

Hence, if $x_n \in [0,4]$, we have $x_n \le  f(x_n) = x_{n+1} \le 4 $.

Hence $x_n$ is non increasing and bounded above and hence there is some
$x \ge x_1 = 1$ such that $x_n \to x$.

Since $f$ is continuous, we have $x = f(x)$. The only non zero solution to
this in $[0,4]$ is $x=4$.

A similar analysis shows that if $x_1 \ge 4$, then the sequence is non
increasing and converges to $4$.

Comment: Thanks. That picture helps out a lot. That is something I can use in my arsenal.

Comment: Glad it helped; I was taught to always try to draw a picture first.

Answer (score 2):

Admit that the limit $L$ exists; so $$L=2\sqrt L$$ which has two solutions $L=0$ and $L=4$.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$x_n =2\sqrt{ x_{n-1}}
$,
taking logs we get
$\log x_n =\log 2 + \frac12 \log x_{n-1}
$.

Letting
$y_n = \log x_n$,
this becomes
$y_n =\log 2 + \frac12  y_{n-1}
$.

You should be able to
establish convergence and
solve this.